# Finding the time complexity of an algorithm with mixed linear and polynomial times

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, curve-fitting

I am trying to work out empirically the complexity of an algorithm I wrote. I have two variables in the input: dataset size (dimensions of a matrix) and number of values computed.

When I look at the complexity varying the number of values it is linear.

[image]

When I look at the complexity varying the set sizes it is polynomial.

[image]

I would like to estimate the complexity coefficients. So,
let T be time, v number of values and s size,

Clearly the intercept and slope of the time versus v increases with s
so I would model it as

T(v; fix s) = (a + b*v)*s

For the size it seems reasonable to take

T(s; fix v) = s^c

how do I put these two together?

T(v, s) = ?

If I fit  log(T) = a + b*log(v) + c*log(s)

I get a perfect fit with Multiple R-squared =  0.9917

a = -5.5   p-value= 7.68e-16 ***

b = 1.7    p-value=  3.10e-12 ***

c = 2.1    p-value=   < 2e-16 ***

[image]

What do I make of these results? They indicate that time is not linear in v
but polynomial v^1.7 (which is not).

Can anyone put me on the right track?

ps I know I should be able to compute the complexity theoretically but I am not :-(

Comment: You need far more than 5 points to interpolate the complexity.

Comment: I wish I had more. But I am also interested in a theoretical answer.

Comment: Maybe post your algorithm here (or a simplified version) and we can help you compute the actual complexity rather than plotting points with data sets and effectively "guessing"

Comment: No, that's beyond my intentions. It would take longer to explain than to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe not the best but it works very well.

I realised that the problem is that the intercepts and slopes of the linear relationships change with the set size. So, I used this model

T(v, s) = a(s) + b(s)*v

To estimate the parameters, first I estimated the coefficients a(s) and b(s) for each set and then regressed these on s. The relationship was still polynomial [log(a(s)) = g + h*log(s), analogously for b(s)]. Surprisingly, it turned out that b(s) = -a(s), so the final separated function is

T(v, s) = 10^k s^2.1(v - 1)

where k is a constant depending on the unit of measure. The fit is almost identical to the polynomial above.

Thanks to all who helped.